# Search drive and copy source to flat target

Tags: command-line, osx, file-copy

I have backups and backups of backups (there are copies of copies) of images spread out over various drives. I want to scan the drives and copy all images from a source to one flat target directory. I will need to avoid certain directories in order to avoid copying things like web image caches. I presume the names are unique, however not the directory names.

To reiterate, I want to find all the images I have created and copy them to one master directory and not have any repeats.

I need to do this on Mac OS X.

What would be my best way of going about this?

Comment: well, you should just copy all the files you want into the directory you want. that's probably about as good an answer as you'll get given the way you've phrased the question.

Comment: which command-line operation would best suit my purpose?

Comment: You can likely do this with find, assuming your backups have a unique extension. See https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-find-and-locate-to-search-for-files-on-a-linux-vps or similar

Comment: nobody's gonna touch this because you give no information at all about file locations, sizes, ownerships, etc, or tree layout whatsoever. anything anyone tells you is mere speculation and might even be dangerous advice to follow considering it was given with so little understanding of the environment. youve gotta tell us what the files are, how theyre named, where they come from and where theyre going. otherwise theres no way to know.